# Why am I getting id="undefined" while using Mozart?

Tags: mozart-mvc

I'm not getting any console logs/errors, but the view I'm trying to create is inserting the DIV without the usual ID:

```
<div id="undefined" view="" class="myclass"></div>
```

Without any errors I'm not sure how to fix this...

view coffee:

```
class App.SidebarView extends Mozart.View
  templateName: 'app/templates/sidebar_view'
  classHtml: 'sidebar-content'

  init: ->
    # stuff to come
```

view hbs just has some placeholder text.

Comment: Without the rest of your code, this is impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call super at the beginning of the init function.

```
init: ->
  super
  #stuff to come
```